# Modify custom view from another class Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have created a custom view in MyView class and want to show or hide `mLevel` using `onSharedPreferenceChanged` method in my MainActivity class.

Here is `MyView.java`:

```
public class MyView extends LinearLayout {

    private final TextView mLevel;

    public StatusBarView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public StatusBarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public StatusBarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_level_view, this);

        mLevel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.levelTextView);
    }

    public void showLevel(boolean bShowLevel) {
    if (bShowLevel) {
        mLevel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mLevel.setText(mService.getLevel());
    } else {
        mLevel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
}
```

And here I have `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Display the fragment as the main content.
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new PrefsFragment()).commit();
}

public class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment
        implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    private TextView mLevel;

    private LevelService mLevelService = new LevelService();

    private MyView mMyView = new MyView(getBaseContext());

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        mLevel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.levelTextView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {

        if (key.equals("showLevel")) {
             mMyView.showLevel(prefs.getBoolean("showLevel", false));       
        }

    }

}
```

But my app crashes when I tap on the Checkbox with `showLevel` key. In Android Studio I get NullPointerException starting on this line: `mLevel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` when trying to modify the View from another class rather than MyView (where it works just fine).

Any help is highly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I've add a `showLevel()` method inside `MyView` and try to access it in a service. Working.

Comment: what is in the `onCreateView()` method of the fragment?

Comment: This is what I have in `MainActivity`, there is no `onCreateView()`. Anyways, I cannot modify the view in neither of my other classes, not only the main one.

Comment: Is `levelTextView` declared in `activity_main.xml`?

Comment: No, it is declared in my_level_view.xml

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SetVisibilityInterface{

private TextView mLevel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mLevel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.levelTextView);
    // Display the fragment as the main content.
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new PrefsFragment(this)).commit();
}

@Override
public void setVisibilityInterfaceAndData(int visibility, String value) {
    if(visibility==View.VISIBLE){
        mLevel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mLevel.setText(value);
    }else {
        mLevel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

public class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment
        implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    private TextView mLevel;
    private Context mContext;
    private LevelService mLevelService = new LevelService();
    private SetVisibilityInterface mySetVisibilityInterface;

    public PrefsFragment(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
        if (key.equals("showLevel")) {
            try {
                mySetVisibilityInterface = (SetVisibilityInterface) mContext;
                if (prefs.getBoolean("showLevel", false)) {
                    mySetVisibilityInterface.setVisibilityInterfaceAndData(View.VISIBLE, mService.getLevel());
                } else {
                    mySetVisibilityInterface.setVisibilityInterfaceAndData(View.GONE, "");
                }
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                throw new ClassCastException(mContext.toString()
                        + " must implement SetVisibilityInterface");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

And for the callBack you will need the interface,

```
public interface SetVisibilityInterface {
public void setVisibilityInterfaceAndData(int visibility, String value);
}
```

Let me know if it works for you,

And mark as an answer so that it would be useful to others...

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm trying to modify/ update `mLevel` in my custom view from the MainActivity class, not to create another `mLevel` inside the Fragment, which by the way is for a PreferenceScreen.

Comment: Well then you can't change the visibility, you will get an exception as View from another class can't be modified from some other class. You will have to call a method of that class and there you set the visibility.

Comment: It looks like if I create a method inside `MyView.java` and run it from a class that extends Service (inside onStartCommand) it will run the code correctly. But I need it to be updated every time there is a change in my Checkbox. Is it possible to add my PrefsFragment using the Service's onStartCommand?